# Old drag and drop code no longer works in windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have some code that allows me to drag and drop a hyperlink from a webpage onto a windows form, and it seperates the URL and the Title and puts them in two different text boxes.

This works on windows XP fine, but on windows 7 it no longer works.  I'm not sure where the difference lies.

```
object data = e.Data.GetData("UniformResourceLocator");
```

data will always be null, but when i use

```
 string[] fmts = e.Data.GetFormats();
```

one of fmts will always be UniformResourceLocator, along with a bunch of other ones that I can never seem to get any data from.  If anyone has an resources to point me to or something I would greatly appreciate it, this is really confusing for me.

Thanks.

UPDATE:added method code that used to work

```
  string hyperLinkUrl = null;
        string hyperLinkText = null;

            hyperLinkUrl = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
            // some browser deliver url and text
            // in UniformResourceLocator (Firebird)
            string[] tokens = null;
            if (hyperLinkUrl != null)
            {
               tokens = hyperLinkUrl.Split('\n');
            }
            if (tokens != null && tokens.Length > 1)
            {
                hyperLinkUrl = tokens[0];
                hyperLinkText = tokens[1];
            }
            // we have to read FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR to get the text (IE)
            else
            {             

                System.IO.Stream ioStream =
                (System.IO.Stream)e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor");
                byte[] contents = new Byte[512];
                try
                {
                    ioStream.Read(contents, 0, 512);
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {

                }    
                ioStream.Close();
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                //The magic number 76 is the size of that part of the
                //FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR structure before
                // the filename starts - cribbed
                //from another usenet post.
                for (int i = 76; contents[i] != 0; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append((char)contents[i]);
                }
                if (!sb.ToString(sb.Length - 4, 4).ToLower().Equals(".url"))
                {
                    throw new Exception("filename does not end in '.url'");
                }
                hyperLinkText = sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 4);
            }
            tbLinkTitle.Text = hyperLinkText;
            tbLinkAddress.Text = hyperLinkUrl;
```

Comment: i added the somewhat sloppy method code

Comment: I'm sorry. When the code says things like `the magic number 76 is the size of that part of the FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR structure before the filename starts`, and you try to use it on a different platform than the one it was written on, all bets are off.

Comment: How does it not work, is the exception fired? Is the parsing off? Details. Details. Details.

Comment: @KyleGobel: Have you inspected the value of your `contents` array to see if there is anything in it? Maybe the position is off and it isn't 76 anymore.

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned, ioStream will be null, I actually can't find a way for e.Data.GetData to not return null stuff, even though e.Data.GetFormats will return a bunch of different formats available.  If I could get any data into the contents byte array I could probably fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [e.data.GetData is always null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422166/e-data-getdata-is-always-null)

Answer (score 4):

> drag and drop a hyperlink from a webpage

That page wouldn't be in a web browser running in low integrity (e.g. IE Protected Mode), would it?  Drag-and-drop doesn't work across integrity levels.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Integrity_Control

What happens if you use `icacls` to set your executable's integrity level to low as well?  If drag-and-drop starts working, this was the problem.